# I'm a collaborator on a private repo that someone else set up, how do I make it public on my profile?

Tags: git, github

My teammate set up the repo for a school project as private while we were working on it. It was considered our portfolio project for the course, so we're allowed to share it after the course ended but my teammate never changed the visibility. I would like to make it visible on my GitHub profile so potential employers can see it when I apply for jobs.

I tried forking it, but the fork is also private with no way for me to change it. So I created a new public repo and just cloned the private one and pushed it to my new public repo. This works to an extent - the code is there and has a history of all the commits, but it doesn't show branches, pull requests, etc., which I would ideally like to keep so you can see all of my contributions.

Assuming I no longer have a way to contact my teammate to ask him to set the original repo to public, is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: You can pull/push all git data (including branches, tags etc) to a new repository but only the owner can change the visibility/ownership of the actual repository and issues/pull requests are not git data/repository but part of the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

How to contact:

- Git by default requires an email
- GitHub allows mentioning people with `@username`

Open the `git log` and check for an email or assemble the email address from the no-reply pattern or create a new issue in the private repo and mention the teammate.

Your teammate should have something useful set either in the git configuration (email) or in GitHub profile, therefore you should be able to reach out. If not, try with the teacher/lecturer. If still no success, let's get to the technical part.

Let's start with replicating the situation on a machine:

1. Your teammate created a repo, somehow, we'll do the simplest case:

```sh
/tmp$ mkdir folder && pushd folder
# /tmp/folder /tmp
/tmp/folder$ mkdir original-repo && pushd original-repo
# /tmp/folder/original-repo /tmp/folder /tmp
/tmp/folder/original-repo$ git init
# Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/folder/original-repo/.git/
```

2. Added some commits, branches, tags:

```sh
/tmp/folder/original-repo$ git commit -m initial --allow-empty
# [master (root-commit) 98f9b79] initial
/tmp/folder/original-repo$ git tag mytag
/tmp/folder/original-repo$ git checkout -b new-branch
# Switched to a new branch 'new-branch'
/tmp/folder/original-repo$ git commit -m new-commit --allow-empty
# [new-branch 8839b1a] new-commit
/tmp/folder/original-repo$ git checkout master
# Switched to branch 'master'
/tmp/folder/original-repo$ popd
# /tmp/folder /tmp
```

3. Pushed it somewhere:

```sh
# how a repo is created via GitHub, cca
/tmp/folder$ mkdir remote-original-repo && pushd remote-original-repo
# /tmp/folder/remote-original-repo /tmp/folder /tmp
/tmp/folder/remote-original-repo$ git init --bare
# Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/folder/remote-original-repo/
/tmp/folder/remote-original-repo$ git branch -a
# <nothing>
```

```sh
/tmp/folder/remote-original-repo$ pushd ../original-repo/
# /tmp/folder/original-repo /tmp/folder/remote-original-repo /tmp/folder /tmp
/tmp/folder/original-repo$ git remote add origin ../remote-original-repo
/tmp/folder/original-repo$ git push --all && git push --tags
# Enumerating objects: 3, done.
# Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
# Delta compression using up to 4 threads
# Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
# Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 257 bytes | 257.00 KiB/s, done.
# Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
# To ../remote-original-repo
#  * [new branch]      master -> master
#  * [new branch]      new-branch -> new-branch
# Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
# To ../remote-original-repo
#  * [new tag]         mytag -> mytag
/tmp/folder/original-repo$ popd
# /tmp/folder/remote-original-repo /tmp/folder /tmp
/tmp/folder/remote-original-repo$ git branch -a && git tag -l
# * master
#   new-branch
# mytag
/tmp/folder/remote-original-repo$ popd
# /tmp/folder /tmp
```

This is the situation now:

1. You've created your clone

```sh
/tmp/folder$ git clone remote-original-repo local-clone
# Cloning into 'local-clone'...
# done.
/tmp/folder$ pushd local-clone/
# /tmp/folder/local-clone /tmp/folder /tmp
/tmp/folder/local-clone$ git branch -a && git tag -l
# * master
#   remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
#   remotes/origin/master
#   remotes/origin/new-branch
# mytag
```

(Git by default pulls all of the branches, but does not mark them for tracking!)

2. Created a repo on a remote location and pushed your branches (i.e. the local ones only)

```sh
/tmp/folder/local-clone$ popd
# /tmp/folder /tmp
/tmp/folder$ mkdir remote-cloned-repo && pushd remote-cloned-repo
# /tmp/folder/remote-cloned-repo /tmp/folder /tmp
/tmp/folder/remote-cloned-repo$ git init --bare
# Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/folder/remote-cloned-repo/
/tmp/folder/remote-cloned-repo$ git branch -a && git tag -l
# <nothing>
/tmp/folder/remote-cloned-repo$ pushd ../local-clone/
# /tmp/folder/local-clone /tmp/folder/remote-cloned-repo /tmp/folder /tmp
/tmp/folder/local-clone$ git remote add my-fork ../remote-cloned-repo
/tmp/folder/local-clone$ git push --all my-fork 
# Enumerating objects: 2, done.
# Counting objects: 100% (2/2), done.
# Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 179 bytes | 179.00 KiB/s, done.
# Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
# To ../remote-cloned-repo
#  * [new branch]      master -> master
/tmp/folder/local-clone$ popd
# /tmp/folder/remote-cloned-repo /tmp/folder /tmp
/tmp/folder/remote-cloned-repo$ git branch -a && git tag -l
# * master
# where is the rest?
```

But not everything was pushed. With git you get all of the branches and tags locally too, but they are not automatically pushed, thus you need to utilize `--all` and `--tags` from your clone as well:

So how to move from here?

1. Track all of the remote branches from `origin` as local ones

```sh
/tmp/folder/remote-cloned-repo$ pushd ../local-clone/
# /tmp/folder/local-clone /tmp/folder/remote-cloned-repo /tmp/folder /tmp
/tmp/folder/local-clone$ for ref in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' --no-merged=origin/HEAD refs/remotes/origin);do git checkout -b $(echo "$ref"|sed -e 's,origin/,,') --track "$ref";done
# Branch 'new-branch' set up to track remote branch 'new-branch' from # 'origin'.
# Switched to a new branch 'new-branch'
```

2. Push all again to your fork remote repository

```sh
/tmp/folder/local-clone$ git push --all my-fork 
# Enumerating objects: 1, done.
# Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
# Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 202 bytes | 202.00 KiB/s, done.
# Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
# To ../remote-cloned-repo
#  * [new branch]      new-branch -> new-branch
/tmp/folder/local-clone$ git push --tags my-fork 
# Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
# To ../remote-cloned-repo
#  * [new tag]         mytag -> mytag
/tmp/folder/local-clone$ popd
# /tmp/folder/remote-cloned-repo /tmp/folder /tmp
/tmp/folder/remote-cloned-repo$ git branch -a && git tag -l
# * master
#   new-branch
# mytag
```

3. (Optional) Delete your clone / create a fresh new clone, so you don't need to play with different origins when pulling/pushing.

Regarding the GitHub repository data. Simple answer is - **NO**. A little bit better answer is copy-pasting it to the new repository both pull requests and issues, but the relevant relationships and merges linked to the repo will already be broken. If you care only about the content, it's still usable. For scalability, utilize [the API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest).

Also note (*tin-foil hat on*), there's a legal aspect to the repository such as present licenses, the code submitted by your teammate, etc, so be sure you're covered in there or simply ask for a permission via email and store the permission somewhere safe.